# SELECT DISTINCT based on a BIT value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server

Table **Jobs**

```
ID   Name   Job    ControlValue
----------------------------------------
1    Seth   IT     0
2    Seth   IT     1
3    Maria  Farmer 1
4    Maria  Farmer 1
5    Maria  Farmer 1
```

This is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Job
  , CASE WHEN ControlValue IS 1 THEN 'Present' WHEN ControlaValue IS 0 THEN 'Not Present'
FROM Jobs
```

This is the output of the above query

```
Name   Job    ControlValue
----------------------------------------
Seth   IT     Not Present
Seth   IT     Present
Maria  Farmer Present
```

What I would like to ask:

- Is there a way to check if there is `ControlValue` with **0** and **1** then show only one row with the result of `Not Present`

So the output would be

```
Name   Job    ControlValue
----------------------------------------
Seth   IT     Not Present
Maria  Farmer Present
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `MIN` and a `CAST`/`CONVERT`:

```
SELECT [Name],
       Job,
       CASE MIN(CONVERT(tinyint,ControlValue)) WHEN 0 THEN 'Not Present' ELSE 'Present' END AS ControlValue
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY [Name],
         Job;
```

The reason you need `CAST`/`CONVERT` here is because you cannot perform aggregate functions on a `bit` data type.

Comment: Flawless answer Sir.

Comment: May I ask you one more question? If there is a statement like `UNION` from another table with the same columns. It's possible to obtain the same results? I've tried it but it gives me error because it says that `Name` is not in a `GROUP BY`, but as we can see `Name` is in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: That would be a separate question, @ChangeWorld . Certainly, however, "Name is not a GROUP BY" is not a SQL Server error.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I summarized the error. So I should ask another question?

Comment: Asking another question isn't a problem, @ChangeWorld . From what you're saying above, you're moving the goal posts (which really annoys people who have taken the time to answer the original question). Just make sure you reference your original question in the new question as well, so people have context.

Comment: Yeah I'm really sorry Sir. I will ask another question. Thank you for the understanding